# How to use access token to like fanpage

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have own access token and i would like create app, where user can like fanpage.

I tested request on `graph.facebook.com`. My request looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkG7x.png

I read documentation form [og.likes documentation on fb](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes)

It was not until I learn to handle fb api

How to sent such a request

```html
curl -X POST \
  -F 'access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -F 'object=OG_OBJECT_URL' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og.likes
```

Answer (score 0):

> The og.likes action can refer to any open graph object or URL, **except for Facebook Pages** or Photos.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes

Use the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) Plugin instead.